# How to list all assets (groupId, name, size) in a Nexus3 repository?

Tags: sql, groovy, nexus, nexus3

I know it is very simple to do in OrientDB :

```
select * from asset where bucket.repository_name = 'my-repo-release';
```

but I need to get this list remotely, not in local orientdb console, so I need a groovy script and I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example script :
https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-scripting-examples

it can be found in the "nexus-script-example" project :

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Asset
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def assetListFile = new File('/tmp/assetListFile.txt')
def request = new JsonSlurper().parseText("{\"repoName\":\"maven-releases\",\"startDate\":\"2016-01-01\"}")

assert request.repoName: 'repoName parameter is required'
assert request.startDate: 'startDate parameter is required, format: yyyy-mm-dd'

log.info("Gathering Asset list for repository: ${request.repoName} as of startDate: ${request.startDate}")

def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(request.repoName)
StorageFacet storageFacet = repo.facet(StorageFacet)
def tx = storageFacet.txSupplier().get()

try {
    tx.begin()
    Iterable<Asset> assets = tx.findAssets(Query.builder().where('last_updated > ').param(request.startDate).build(), [repo])

    assets.each {Asset asset ->
        assetListFile << asset.name() + '\n'
    }
}
finally {
    tx.close()
}
```

All properties of an asset (object org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Asset) are accessible, including asset.size().